# Recorrer e insertar con put un json a SQLite usando Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, sqlite

estoy intentando insertar los datos que tengo desde un json que he armado a través de una consulta SQL a SQLite usando Kotlin, tengo mi modelo:

```
class VarietyModel(
id: Int?,
idconsumidor: String,
jerarquia: String,
descripcion: String,
idccosto: String,
idsucursal: String,
) {
var id: Int? = null;
var idconsumidor: String? = null;
var jerarquia: String? = null;
var descripcion: String? = null;
var idccosto: String? = null;
var idsucursal: String? = null;

init {
    this.id = id;
    this.idconsumidor = idconsumidor;
    this.jerarquia = jerarquia;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.idccosto = idccosto;
    this.idsucursal = idsucursal;
}
```

Luego mi función para insertar:

```
    fun insertVariety(vari: VarietyModel){
    val db:SQLiteDatabase =  helper?.writableDatabase!!

    val contentValues = ContentValues()
    contentValues.put(tareoContract.Companion.apiContract.ID, vari.id)
    contentValues.put(tareoContract.Companion.apiContract.IDCONSUMIDOR, vari.idconsumidor)
    contentValues.put(tareoContract.Companion.apiContract.JERARQUIA, vari.jerarquia)
    contentValues.put(tareoContract.Companion.apiContract.DESCRIPCION, vari.descripcion)
    contentValues.put(tareoContract.Companion.apiContract.IDCCOSTO, vari.idccosto)
    contentValues.put(tareoContract.Companion.apiContract.IDSUCURSAL, vari.idsucursal)

}
```

Y aquí tengo mi función en la cual valido si estoy conectado a internet es donde lo quiero insertar:

```
fun callNetworkConnection() {

    network = Network(application)
    network.observe(this, { isConnected ->
        if (isConnected) {

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_connect_without_contact_24)
            textView.setText("ACTUALIZACION EXITOSA")
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3CD636"))

            val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
            val url = "http://199.241.218.53:60000/VLB/Vistas/rrhh/action/variety_to_tareo.php"

            val stringRequest = StringRequest(
                Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener
                { response ->
                    val status = crud?.insertVariety(VarietyModel())<-- Lo quiero insertar desde aqui
                },

                Response.ErrorListener { error ->

                    error.message?.let { Log.d("HTTP_REQUEST", it) }

                })

        }else{
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_connect_without_contact_25)
            textView.setText("NO HAY INTERNET")
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D63636"))
            }
        })
    }
}
```

El json que recibo tiene esta estructura:

```
[{"ID":"001","CONSUMIDOR":"CP21CCI ","JERARQUIA":"010.005.001.001","DESCRIPCION":"CITRICO CH 21","IDCCOSTO":"CP21CCI ","IDSUCURSAL":"002"},
{"ID":"001","CONSUMIDOR":"CP21PAL ","JERARQUIA":"010.005.001.002","DESCRIPCION":"PALTO CH 21","IDCCOSTO":"CP21PAL ","IDSUCURSAL":"002"},
{"ID":"001","CONSUMIDOR":"CP21ANT ","JERARQUIA":"010.005.001.003","DESCRIPCION":"ANTILLANO CH 21","IDCCOSTO":"CP21ANT ","IDSUCURSAL":"002"},
{"ID":"001","CONSUMIDOR":"CP21CLO ","JERARQUIA":"010.005.001.004","DESCRIPCION":"CLONAL CH 21","IDCCOSTO":"CP21CLO ","IDSUCURSAL":"002"},
{"ID":"001","CONSUMIDOR":"CP21CAQ ","JERARQUIA":"010.005.001.005","DESCRIPCION":"CAQUI CH 21","IDCCOSTO":"CP21CAQ ","IDSUCURSAL":"002"}]
```

¿Como recorro el json que recibo y como lo inserto en SQLite?
Si alguien tiene una guía o algún consejo que me permite avanzar, me sería de mucha ayuda.

Comment: "¿Como recorro el json que recibo y como lo inserto en SQLite? " Debes agregar un ejemplo de la estructura del json que obtienes, eso determina como obtend`ras sus valores

Comment: Ok, los acabo de agregar, e estado tratando de buscar info y no he encontrado mucha.

Comment: he agregado una respuesta para obtener los valores y enviarlos a tu mètodo  insertVariety(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir de la respuesta que obtienes, que es un array que contiene varios objetos,

```
[{"ID":"001","CONSUMIDOR":"CP21CCI ","JERARQUIA":"010.005.001.001","DESCRIPCION":"CITRICO CH 21","IDCCOSTO":"CP21CCI ","IDSUCURSAL":"002"},
{"ID":"001","CONSUMIDOR":"CP21PAL ","JERARQUIA":"010.005.001.002","DESCRIPCION":"PALTO CH 21","IDCCOSTO":"CP21PAL ","IDSUCURSAL":"002"},
{"ID":"001","CONSUMIDOR":"CP21ANT ","JERARQUIA":"010.005.001.003","DESCRIPCION":"ANTILLANO CH 21","IDCCOSTO":"CP21ANT ","IDSUCURSAL":"002"},
{"ID":"001","CONSUMIDOR":"CP21CLO ","JERARQUIA":"010.005.001.004","DESCRIPCION":"CLONAL CH 21","IDCCOSTO":"CP21CLO ","IDSUCURSAL":"002"},
{"ID":"001","CONSUMIDOR":"CP21CAQ ","JERARQUIA":"010.005.001.005","DESCRIPCION":"CAQUI CH 21","IDCCOSTO":"CP21CAQ ","IDSUCURSAL":"002"}]
```

obten el array e itera sobre sus objetos obteniendo las propiedades.

A partir de la respuesta (variable `response`) este serìa el còdigo:

```
        val jsonArray = JSONArray(response)
        //Itera sobre los objetos contenidos en el array json
        for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {

            //Obtiene valores del objeto Json.
            val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
            var id = jsonObject.getString("ID")
            var idconsumidor = jsonObject.getString("CONSUMIDOR")
            var jerarquia = jsonObject.getString("JERARQUIA")
            var descripcion = jsonObject.getString("DESCRIPCION")
            var idcosto = jsonObject.getString("IDCCOSTO")
            var idsucursal = jsonObject.getString("IDSUCURSAL")


            //Crea objeto VarietyModel
            var vari: VarietyModel = VarietyModel(id.toInt(),idconsumidor,jerarquia,descripcion,idcosto,idsucursal)
            //Inserta valores.
            insertVariety(vari: VarietyModel)
        }
```

Comment: Perfecto @Elanasys, me sirvió, muchas gracias.